# Как сделать чтобы бот мог одновременно ожидать сообщение и нажатия на inline кнопку telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Суть такая, бот присылает сообщение с инлайн клавиатурой и ждёт нажатие одной из кнопок и при этом пользователь должен иметь возможность не нажимать на кнопку, а отправить сообщение, подскажите пожалуйста как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

`register_next_step_handler` для ожидания ввода

`delete_message` для удаления сообщения с клавиатурой после ввода текста

`edit_message_text` для изменения сообщения после нажатия кнопки

```
button = {'button_1': '1', 'button_2': '2', 'button_3': '3', 'button_4': '4'}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn = []
    for i in button.items():
        key = InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'кнопка {i[1]}', callback_data=i[0])
        btn.append(key)
    kb.add(*btn)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'привет', reply_markup=kb)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'на предыдушем шаге вы ввели: {message.text}')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline_kb(call):
    if call.data in button:
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text=f'вы нажали кнопку {button[call.data]}')
```